# get routes in especial language in laravel5

Tags: laravel, laravel-localization

I have 2 languages in my laravel.

for example, when I print

```
route('home');
```

in France page,

it prints: `http://127.0.0.1/8000/fr`

and in english: `http://127.0.0.1/8000/en`

How can I print `http://127.0.0.1/8000/en` in France page?

(each page of my site has a translate with same address but differ in 'en' and 'fr').

for example:

```
http://example.com/en/artcile/123


http://example.com/fr/artcile/123
```

I did it before. Now I only want put link of translated page in its page. (France link in English page and English link in France page)

I know, I could do it manually via {{url('')}} ..but could I do it via route? (Especially for more complicated routes)

Comment: see laravel localization

Comment: check this [package](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization)

Comment: is it only toggle or list of language you have ?